# How to fully close a door

Tags: doors

I have a problem. My door, when it closes doesn't completely close. The lower part of the door manages to rest next to the door frame. But the upper part of the door leaves a lot of space between the door frame and the door. In other words, it isn't properly closed.

This is the door to my room and it has a latch bolt and strike plate on the outside. I would like to fix this but I don't want to damage the door. I'm sure there's something that could be done, but I ask for your help.

Comment: How old is the door, is it original to the home? There is a few way to take care of the problem depending if it is a split jamb or solid jamb. How old it is will say a little about that unless you know that it is solid or split...

Comment: what is your concern over it not closing completely? Are you trying to keep sound or light out of the room, or keep your heat in, or does it just irk you to see that gap?

Answer (score 1):

The door or frame could be warped, which means replacing or rebuilding one of them.

It's also possible that the door is simply poorly installed, in which case moving the hinges around would solve it.

When you close the door, if TWO corners (out of four) of the door and frame meet, then you can probably get by with moving the hinges. If THREE corners meet, then you've got a warped door or frame.